# How does Neo4j get into a deadlock if it's only being accessed via the non-transactional REST API?

Tags: neo4j

I have an app that only talks to Neo4j via the non-transactional REST API. That means it's only ever performing one discreet action per transaction, and there are no long-running transactions or anything like that.

How am I ending up with deadlocks?

> DeadlockDetectedException: Don't panic. A deadlock scenario has been detected and avoided. This means that two or more transactions, which were holding locks, were wanting to await locks held by one another, which would have resulted in a deadlock between these transactions. This exception was thrown instead of ending up in that deadlock. See the deadlock section in the Neo4j manual for how to avoid this: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-deadlocks.html Details: 'Transaction(9410045, owner:"qtp1945281084-26885")[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=1] can't wait on resource RWLock[RelationshipLock[id=287871]] since => Transaction(9410045, owner:"qtp1945281084-26885")[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=1] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[Node[101401]] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- Transaction(9410047, owner:"qtp1945281084-26888")[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=1] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[RelationshipLock[id=287871]]'.

Comment: Did you ever figure out your issue? Facing similar difficulties, finding it difficult to determine what is the proper scenario.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what your do on your REST calls. Imagine that you have a lot of calls that remove relationships. Removing a relationship puts a lock on all the nodes connected by that relationship, so multiple calls would want to lock the same nodes.